# ¿Objeto dentro de otro objeto en JAVA?

Tags: java, poo, objeto

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente código

El programa en si es una aplicación que se presentaría por la consola solamente. Se debe permitir el ingreso, consulta, modificaron y eliminación de estudiantes, profesores, secretarios, conserjes y calificaciones.

Se debe ingresar como un tipo de usuario y cada tipo de usuario tiene ciertas limitaciones:

En este caso estamos desarrollando el apartado del administrador, el cual puede hacer todo. El problema surge al momento de ingresar las materias y fechas, pues estas dos deben de ser tratadas como objetos con sus propios atributos, y al mismo tiempo estas están dentro de cada uno de los usuarios.

En el programa actual, el admin puede hacer lo que debe pero las materias y fechas no son tratadas como objetos, y eso es justo lo que queremos saber, como hacer que el programa funcione tratando a las fechas y materias como objetos, que estén dentro de cada usuario en el campo que lo necesite.

Por ejemplo, en el caso de `f_inicio`, fecha de inicio de semestre, que pertenece a `Estudiante`, debería ser tratado como un objeto de la clase `Fecha` con sus respectivos atributos de (Año, mes, día, hora, minuto y segundo) y lo mismo con las materias.

Estos son los atributos necesarios, y la clase a la que deben de pertenecer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código desarrollado hasta el momento:

### Código Principal

```java
import java.util.*; 

public class ProyectoPOO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int TipoPersona,Sistema=1,Accion,Aux,Tipo;
        
        LinkedList LE= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LP= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LS= new LinkedList();
        LinkedList LC= new LinkedList();
        
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su tipo de usuario:");
            System.out.println("1. Estudiante");
            System.out.println("2. Profesor");
            System.out.println("3. Secretario");
            System.out.println("4. Conserje");
            System.out.println("5. Administrador");
            System.out.println("6. Salir");
            TipoPersona=sc.nextInt();
            switch(TipoPersona){
            
            case 1: //Estudiante
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 2: //Profesor
                do{
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("2. Modificar Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("3. Consultar Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("4. Cierre de Calificaciones");
                System.out.println("5. Consulta tipo acta de calificación de estudiante por materia");
                System.out.println("6. Retroceder");
                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch(Accion){
                        case 1: //Ingreso de Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 2: //Modificar Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 3: //Consultar Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 4: //Cierre de Calificaciones
                        break;
                        case 5: //Consulta tipo acta de calificación de estudiante por materia
                        break;
                        case 6: //Retroceder
                        Sistema=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }while(Sistema==1);
                Sistema=1;
            break;
            
            case 3: //Secretario
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 4: //Conserje
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
            break;
            
            case 5: //Administrador
                do{
                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
                System.out.println("1. Modificar Estudiantes");
                System.out.println("2. Modificar Profesores");
                System.out.println("3. Modificar Secretarias");
                System.out.println("4. Modificar Conserjes");
                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                    switch(Accion){
                        case 1: //Estudiantes
                            Tipo=1;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Estudiantes?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Estudiantes");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Estudiante");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Estudiante
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LE);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size()); //Para asegurar q se guardan los objetos
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Estudiantes
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Estudiante
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posición del estudiante del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificación");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LE);
                                        LE.set(Aux,LE.getLast());
                                        LE.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LE.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LE);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posición del Estudiante a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LE.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 2: //Profesores
                            Tipo=2;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Profesores?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Profesores");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Profesores");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar profesor
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LP);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar profesor
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos profesor
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posición del profesor del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificacion");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LP);
                                        LP.set(Aux,LP.getLast());
                                        LP.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar profesor
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LP.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LP);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del profesor a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LP.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 3: //Secretarios
                            Tipo=3;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de Secretarios?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Secretario");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar SecretarioS");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Secretario");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Secretario");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Secretario
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LS);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Secretario
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Secretario
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posición del Secretario del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificación");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LS);
                                        LS.set(Aux,LS.getLast());
                                        LS.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LS.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LS);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posición del Secretario a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LS.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 4: //Conserje
                            Tipo=4;
                            do{
                                System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer en el apartado de ConserjeS?");
                                System.out.println("1. Ingresar Conserje");
                                System.out.println("2. Consultar Conserjes");
                                System.out.println("3. Modificar Datos Conserje");
                                System.out.println("4. Eliminar Conserje");
                                System.out.println("5. Retroceder");
                                Accion=sc.nextInt();
                                switch(Accion){
                            
                                    case 1: //Ingresar Conserje
                                        
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LC);
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Consultar Conserje
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Modificar Datos Conserje
                                        
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del Conserje del cual modificara sus datos");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese nueva modificación");
                                        ingresoDatos(Tipo,LC);
                                        LC.set(Aux,LC.getLast());
                                        LC.removeLast();
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 4: //Eliminar Estudiante
                                        System.out.println("Cantidad de Figuras en el LinkedList:"+LC.size());
                                        mostrarDatos(LC);
                                        System.out.println("Ingrese la posición del Conserje a eliminar:");
                                        Aux=sc.nextInt();
                                        LC.remove(Aux);
                                    break;
                                    
                                    case 5: //Retroceder
                                        Sistema=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            
                            }while(Sistema==1);
                            Sistema=1;
                        break;
                        
                        case 5: //Retroceder
                        Sistema=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }while(Sistema==1);
                Sistema=1;
            break;
            case 6: //Salir del Sistema
                Sistema=0;
            break;}
        }while(Sistema==1);

    }

    public static void mostrarDatos(LinkedList lista)
    {
        Persona p;
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();++i)
        {
            p=(Persona)lista.get(i);
            System.out.println(i+" - "+p.mostrar());
        }
    }
    
        
    public static void ingresoDatos(int Tipo,LinkedList lista)
    {
        String nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestre,f_inicio,f_final,materias_semestre;
        String carreras,materias;
        String f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre:");
            nombre=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido:");
            apellido=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su cedula:");
            cedula=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
            edad=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento:");
            f_nacimiento=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su telefono:");
            telefono=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su direccion:");
            direccion=sc.nextLine();
            
        
        if (Tipo == 1){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su semestre:");
            semestre=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su f_inicio:");
            f_inicio=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su f_final:");
            f_final=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su materias_semestre:");
            materias_semestre=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Estudiante(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestre,f_inicio,f_final,materias_semestre));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 2){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus carreras:");
            carreras=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese materias que dicta:");
            materias=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Profesor(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carreras,materias));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 3){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su fecha de inicio:");
            f_ingreso=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana o tarde):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 4){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su fecha de inicio:");
            f_ingreso=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana, tarde o noche):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Clase Abstracta Persona

```java
public abstract class Persona{
    
    protected String nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion;
    
    public Persona(String nombre,String apellido,String cedula,String edad,String f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion)
    {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
        this.cedula=cedula;
        this.edad=edad;
        this.f_nacimiento=f_nacimiento;
        this.telefono=telefono;
        this.direccion=direccion;
    }
    
    public abstract String mostrar();
    
}
```

---

### Clase Estudiante

```java
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    
    protected String carrera,semestre,f_inicio,f_final,materias_semestre;
    
    public Estudiante(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, String edad, String f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,String carrera,String semestre,String f_inicio,String f_final,String materias_semestre){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carrera=carrera;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.f_inicio=f_inicio;
        this.f_final=f_final;
        this.materias_semestre=materias_semestre;
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
    
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+semestre+" "+f_inicio+" "+f_final+" "+materias_semestre);
    }

}
```

---

### Clase Profesor

```java
public class Profesor extends Persona{
    
    protected String carreras,materias;
    
    public Profesor(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, String edad, String f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,String carreras,String materias){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carreras=carreras;
        this.materias=materias;
        
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
    
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carreras+" "+materias);
    }
}
```

---

### Clase Secretario

```java
public class Secretario extends Persona{
    
    protected String carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno;
    
    public Secretario(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, String edad, String f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,String carrera,String fecha_ingreso,String años_servicio,String turno){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carrera=carrera;
        this.f_ingreso=fecha_ingreso;
        this.años_servicio=años_servicio;
        this.turno=turno;
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
        
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+f_ingreso+" "+años_servicio+" "+turno);
    }
}
```

---

### Clase Conserje

```java
public class Conserje extends Persona{
    
    protected String carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno;
    
    public Conserje(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, String edad, String f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,String carrera,String fecha_ingreso,String años_servicio,String turno){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carrera=carrera;
        this.f_ingreso=fecha_ingreso;
        this.años_servicio=años_servicio;
        this.turno=turno;
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
    
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+f_ingreso+" "+años_servicio+" "+turno);
    }  
}
```

---

### Clase Fecha

```java
public class Fecha {
    
    protected String año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg;
    
    public Fecha(String año,String mes,String dia,String hora,String min,String seg)
    {
        this.año=año;
        this.mes=mes;
        this.dia=dia;
        this.hora=hora;
        this.min=año;
        this.seg=seg;
    }
}
```

---

### Clase Materia

```java
public class Materia {
    
    protected String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestre, id_carrera;
    protected LinkedList calificaciones;
    
    public Materia(String nombre_materia,String codigo_materia, String semestre, String id_carrera, LinkedList calificaciones)
    {
        this.nombre_materia=nombre_materia;
        this.codigo_materia=codigo_materia;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.id_carrera=id_carrera;
        this.calificaciones=calificaciones;
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que se deba de hacer es crear una clase `Fecha`, el cual usted ya tiene, sin embargo todos los atributos son de tipo String y eso va a ser un problema

```
protected String año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg;

public Fecha(String año,String mes,String dia,String hora,String min,String seg)
{
    this.año=año;
    this.mes=mes;
    this.dia=dia;
    this.hora=hora;
    this.min=año;
    this.seg=seg;
}
```

Ahora voy a hacer unos cambios

```
public class Fecha{
 /*Declaramos todos los atributos privados y de tipo int, de esta forma si tiene que hacer validaciones (ej: si la fecha es valida. Con String pueden ingresar caracteres) */
  private int año;
  private int mes;
  private int dia;
  private int hora;
  private int minuto;
  private int segundos;

  public Fecha(int año, int mes, int dia, int hora, int minuto, int segundos){
    this.año = año;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.dia = dia;
   /*... los demas */
  }
}
```

Ahora veremos como debe quedar la clase Estudiante con respecto a la clase Fecha

```
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
  //Declare los atributos uno por uno
  private String carrera;
  private String semestre;
  //Declaramos un atributo de tipo Fecha
  private Fecha fechaInicio; //En java es más usado el stadar camelCase
  private Fecha fechaFinal;
  //Como Materia es un tipo de dato y son varias materias en eun semestre, creamos una lista de objetos Materia
  private List<Materia> materiasSemestre; 
  
  //Creamos el constructor
  public Estudiante(String nombre, String Apellido, String cedula, String edad,
                     Fecha fechaNacimiento, String telefono, String direccion,
                     String carrera, String semestre, Fecha fechaInicio, 
                     Fecha fechaFinal, List<Materia> materiasSemestre){
    super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,fechaNacimiento,telefono,direccion);
    this.carrera = carrera;
    this.semestre = semestre;
    this.fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
    this.fechaFinal = fechaFinal;
    this.materiasSemestre = materiasSemestre;
  }
... mas métodos
}
```

Comment: Listo muchas gracias su comentario ha sido de gran utilidad para completar el código.

Answer (score 1):

respondiendo a tu pregunta si es posible tener objetos instanciados en otros objetos, solo que recuerda en tus constructores de los objetos inicializarlos y que estos deben estar como atributos de tu objeto

un ejemplo es el siguiente

suponiendo que tenmos los objetos "fecha" y "materias" como los objetos que se van a instanciar dentro de nuestro objeto principal quedaria algo asi

```
 class persona{
      //atributos
      private String nombre, apellidos, sexo;
      private int Edad;
      
      //introducimos los objetos como atributos
      private fecha f1;
      private materias m1;
      
      /* f1 y m1 es como las identificaremos dentro de nuestro objeto principal
      espero en esta parte no confindirte */

      //ahora declararemos nuestros constructores 

      persona(){ //Constructor sin argumentos
         nombre=""; //en lugar de "" pueden ser valores por defecto 
         apellidos="";
         sexo="";
         f1 = new fecha();
         m1 = new materias();
      }

      //Constructor con argumentos
      persona(String nombre, String apellidos, String sexo, fecha f1, materias m1 ){ 
         this.nombre= nombre; 
         this.apellidos=apellidos;
         this.sexo=sexo;
         this.f1 = f1;
         this.m1 = m1;
      }

       //Todos tus metodos
          °
          °
          ° 
    }
```

espero te ayude un poco con tus dudas es muy general este ejemplo pero creo te puede ayudar a entender lo que debes hacer

Y Concuerdo con el comentario anterior, cambia el tipo de dato que estas utilizando en los atributos del objeto fecha

Comment: Listo muchas gracias su comentario ha sido de gran utilidad para completar el código.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoVeraGarcia recuerda aceptar la respuesta que soluciono tu problema y/o aclaró tu duda.